# CSS Transition from center

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have some horizontal lines, made using `div` elements. All of them animate by using CSS, to set the transition, and JS, to set the new `width`. Here's my current code and result:

HTML:

```
<div style="bottom: 10%;" class="lines-horizontal"></div>
<div style="bottom: 20%;" class="lines-horizontal"></div>
<div style="bottom: 30%;" class="lines-horizontal"></div>
<div style="bottom: 40%;" class="lines-horizontal"></div>
<div style="bottom: 50%;" class="lines-horizontal"></div>
<div style="bottom: 60%;" class="lines-horizontal"></div>
<div style="bottom: 70%;" class="lines-horizontal"></div>
<div style="bottom: 80%;" class="lines-horizontal"></div>
<div style="bottom: 90%;" class="lines-horizontal"></div>
<div style="bottom: 100%;" class="lines-horizontal"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.lines-horizontal {
  position: relative;
  width: 0%;
  transition: width 2s;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -5;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
var horizontalLines = document.getElementsByClassName("lines-horizontal")
for (var hLines = 0; hLines < horizontalLines.length; hLines++) {
  horizontalLines[hLines].style.width = "100%"
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/u5Lfu11j/4/

The problem here is that the lines start animating starting from the left. Just like there's a `transform-origin` property, is there any way I can do the same except for transitioning/animating? I want to be able to set the lines to start from the center and expand outwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about an easier solution by using only one element and gradient background then animate the background size **without JS**:

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 30%,transparent 30%);
  background-size:0% 20px;
  background-position:50% 0;
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  animation:anim 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes anim {
  from{
    background-size:0% 20px;
  }
  to {
    background-size:100% 20px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You can also consider them as different element in case you want to animate them differently:

```css
.line {
  height: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.line:nth-child(1) {
  animation: anim 2s forwards;
}
.line:nth-child(2) {
  animation: anim 2s forwards 0.5s;
}
.line:nth-child(3) {
  animation: anim 2s forwards 1s;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    background-size: 0% 100%;
  }
  to {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="line">
  </div>
  <div class="line">
  </div>
  <div class="line">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`margin: auto` will give you the desired transition from center:

```
.lines-horizontal {
  position: relative;
  width: 0%;
  transition: width 2s;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -5;
  margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u5Lfu11j/22/